# Python: ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape') when using nelson_siegel_svensson module

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a maturity column and a yield column (both float) and I'm trying to compute an nelson siegel svensson (NSS) curve.

I'm using:

```
from nelson_siegel_svensson import NelsonSiegelSvenssonCurve
from nelson_siegel_svensson.calibrate import calibrate_nss_ols

y = df['yield']
t = df['maturity']  
    
curve, status = calibrate_nss_ols(t, y) 
assert status.success
print(curve)
```

And I'm getting:
raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')

Which seems to be occurring when nelson_siegel_svensson tries to reference numpy with:

```
return np.stack([constant, factor1, factor2, factor3]).transpose()
```

I've double checked and my y and t arrays have the same dimensions.

I read something online about trying np.column_stack, but because NSS isn't my code I'm not that sure where I should add it in or why I would need it.

Comment: `stack` requires that those 4 arrays all have the same shape.  But without the full traceback (and possibly looking at `nelson...` source code, we can't trace those arrays back to your arguments.

Comment: What does the `nelson...` docs say about the `t` and `y` arguments?  What does it expect?  numpy arrays with certain dimensions?  Is it ok with Pandas `Series` (which is what your `y` and `t` are)?  It may actually be using `t.values` etc.  Keep in mind that few, if any of us, have used `nelson_siegel_svensson`.  I don't even know its source. (and there isn't a relevant `tag`).

Comment: t and y are expected to be numpy arrays, in the example on pypi they are the same length which is what I would expect for a yield curve too.

The output should look like this, i.e. just a single value for each of constant, factor1, factor2, factor3
NelsonSiegelCurve(constant=0.04201739383636799, factor1=-0.031829031569430594, factor2=-0.026797319779108236, factor3=1.7170972656534174)

Comment: Please copy/paste the full error trace (not just the final error) so people who want to help can do so.

Comment: Thanks. Have got it sorted. I just needed:

Comment: y = np.array(bonds['yield']) instead of y = bonds['yield]' and same again for t. So wrong data type.